# How to make the keyboard go above my content?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: https://imgur.com/GDUUrnM]

[image: https://imgur.com/A0IFXYJ]

Do you know how can I make my keyboard go above all the content?
Because I can see that flutter thinks that my keyboard is like a container which needs some space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html) is use to specify the behavior for this case.
Just set it to `false` to make the keyboard go above your content:

```dart
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  ...
)
```

Comment: @hupdd I think this also causes it to cover your content if you happen to be on a smaller device. Make sure you test with small screens.